# How to find nested comments using regex groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find all comments in a piece of text with c# using regex. 
Comments looks like:

```
(*Some comment text*)
(*Some comment (*In comment*) might also appear*)
(*Comment might 
be on serveral lines*)
```

The start of a comment is `(*`
The end of a comment is `*)`

Finding the comment is not so hard as long as it is not nested:
`\(\*(.*?)\*\)`

I have also found solutions for comments where starting and or ending of the comment exists out of only one character (in the example below start is `(` and end is `)`). This works for nested comments:

`(?<Open>[(])(([^()]|(?<Open>[(])|(?<-Open>[)]))*?)(?<-Open>[)])(?(Open)(?!))`

The solution above relies on finding alternatives => The opening group, the closing group or anything that is not the opening and closing group.

It's the last part that is tricky. 
How can i tell regex that `[^()]` should be a combination of chararcters instead of separate ones.
What i would like to do is this:

`(?<Open>\(\*)(([^\(\*,\*\)]|(?<Open>\(\*)|(?<-Open>\*\)))*?)(?<-Open>\*\))(?(Open)(?!))`

But `[^\(\*,\*\)]` should be seen as - not `(*" and also not "*)` - instead of - not any of these `(*,*)` characters -

Comment: What data example fails your nested loops? I believe the answer lies not with in the current pattern, but a different one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The example I have trouble with catching is this `(*Some comment (*In comment*) might also appear*)` The result should be the whole string from first `(*` to last `*)` instead of `(*Some comment (*In comment*)`. I have not yet found a suitable pattern for this. I know there are solutions other than regex that can solve this problem, but it baffles me that regex would not be able to handle this. I'm open to suggestions :)